# How can I save my form from website into mongo database

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, ejs

I have a testing website where when a patient logs in he is asked to fill a form out, my server is connected to my mongodb , and when the post request is submited I was hoping to save it in my database but nothing really happens. If someone can help me fix this issue. Is it possible to connect form from data to mongo database.

server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const HealthRecord = require('./models/health-records.js');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.listen(4000);
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/hospital')
console.log('connected to database')
// In-memory user database for testing purposes
const users = [
  { username: 'nurse', password: 'nurse', role: 'nurse' },
  { username: 'patient', password: 'patient', role: 'patient' },
];

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.render('index.ejs', { message: '' });
});

app.post('/', (req, res) => {
  const { username, password } = req.body;
  const user = users.find(u => u.username === username && u.password === password);

  if (user) {
    // Redirect to different routes based on user role
    if (user.role === 'nurse') {
      res.redirect('/nurse');
    } else if (user.role === 'patient') {
      res.redirect('/patient');
    }
  } else {
    res.render('index.ejs', { message: 'Invalid username or password' });
  }
});

app.get('/nurse', (req, res) => {
  // Render nurse dashboard or perform additional nurse-specific logic
  res.render('nurse-dashboard.ejs', { username: 'nurse' });
});

app.get('/patient', (req, res) => {
  // Render patient dashboard or perform additional patient-specific logic
  res.render('patient-dashboard.ejs', { username: 'patient' });
});

app.post('/patient', async (req, res) => {
  try {

    const healthRecord = await HealthRecord.create(req.body);
    res.redirect('/patient');
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error.message);
    res.status(500).json({ message: error.message });
  }
});
```

health-records.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const healthSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, "Enter a name asap"]
    },
    height: {
        type: Number,
        default: 0,
        required: true
    },
    race: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    eyeColor: {
        type: String,
        required: false
    },
    bloodPressure: {
        type: Number,
        required: false
    },
    temperature: {
        type: Number,
        required: false
    }
}, {
    timestamps: true
});

const HealthRecord = mongoose.model('health_records', healthSchema);
module.exports = HealthRecord;



<!-- enter-details.ejs -->
<html>
<head>
  <title>Enter Details</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Enter Details</h1>
  <form action="/enter-details" method="post">
    <label for="name">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" required><br>

    <label for="height">Height:</label>
    <input type="number" id="height" name="height" required><br>

    <label for="race">Race:</label>
    <input type="text" id="race" name="race" required><br>

    <label for="eyeColor">Eye Color:</label>
    <input type="text" id="eyeColor" name="eyeColor" required><br>

    <label for="bloodPressure">Blood Pressure:</label>
    <input type="number" id="bloodPressure" name="bloodPressure" required><br>

    <label for="temperature">Temperature:</label>
    <input type="number" id="temperature" name="temperature" required><br>

    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>

  <p><a href="/">Back to Home</a></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Patient dashboard

Comment: Your form is posting to `/enter-details` but you don't have a route handler for that.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this issue ,Your HTML form should match the endpoint in your Express route.

```
Change :
<form action="/enter-details" method="post">
```

with this and try :

```
 <form action="/patient" method="post">
```